# How can I accept credit card transaction in my Web Apps?

Tags: e-commerce, credit-card

I am writing a e-commercial site which allow user check out using the credit card, how can I accept customers' credit card to do transaction??

Answer (score 1):

Various methods. [Paypal](http://www.paypal.com) is a quick and easy option, or you can go with a service like [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) which will cost a bit, but will also provide a quick and commonly-used payment-gateway.

Depending on the ecommerce solution you're using, there are likely several creditcard-modules already developed by the community of users.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the most easy ways are [PayPal](http://paypal.com) and [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com/). many others also exist. Depends on what exactly you want. Also, depending on your website, several ready-made solutions for shopping carts are available (ZenCart?).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said PayPal is good tool amongst others to use. Having successfully done an integration with PayPal, I found the integration to be very straight forward and painless. [Here](https://www.x.com/index.jspa) is the link to the developer site, where you can find documentation, code samples and sandbox access to simulate Credit Card Transactions. I hope this helps.